# ngFor Observable with async pipe in ngIf displays no results

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've got an input with dropdown list that isn't displaying results. It in an ngIf with async. The dropdown list is displayed when I remove the ngIf code so I think it must be either the ngIf check or how I've setup the test observable service. When I press a key entering 1 value nothing is displayed, the second time I enter a key it displays the list.

```
<div class="format-options" *ngIf="(definitions | async)?.length > 0">
  <div *ngFor="let definition of definitions | async" class="search-result">
    <div>{{definition.name}}</div>
    <div>{{definition.description}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Search Service:

```
searchTerm(term: string): Observable<Array<ObjectDefinition>>

    let observer = new Observable<Array<ObjectDefinition>>((subscription) => {

      const timer$ = interval(1000);

      timer$.subscribe(() => {
        console.log('timer 1 second');
        subscription.next(this.objectDefinitions);
        subscription.complete();
      });

    });

    return observer;
}
```

Component:

```
constructor(private definitionService: DefinitionService) {
    this.definitions = this.searchInput.valueChanges
                        .pipe(
                            tap(value => console.log('input')),
                            //startWith(''),
                            debounceTime(500),
                            //distinctUntilChanged(),
                            switchMap(value => this.definitionService.searchTerm(value))
                        );
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit on your code. I actually don't understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: You should never subscribe in services, use rxjs operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the first `*ngIf` subscribes through the `async` pipe. Once this returns a result, the observable completes, and the `*ngFor` tries to susbcribe to an already completed observable which does not replays it's last emit. You can fix this by adding a `shareReplay(1)` pipe:

```
this.definitions = this.searchInput.valueChanges.pipe(
  tap(value => console.log('input')),
  debounceTime(500),
  switchMap(value => this.definitionService.searchTerm(value)),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

The whole `searchTerm` observable looks a bit weirdly constructed though, and you should have a look at how to improve that one, but it's a bit difficult to see what you want to achieve there. Are you trying to debounce it by 1000ms and only emit once?

To prevent the use of double subscriptions in your template, you can also change your template a bit:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="definitions | async as defs">
  <div class="format-options" *ngIf="defs.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let definition of defs" class="search-result">
      <div>{{definition.name}}</div>
      <div>{{definition.description}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha I like how we both used `as defs` :D One of the reasons i always name observables with a `$` at the end.

Comment: Yeah I do this too, but im too lazy to update his ts code xD

Comment: Like debounce, a timed response and I wanted some example observable code in project because I'm new to rxjs

Comment: substituting a http response, no server setup too

Comment: your service code can be simplified to `of(this.objectDefinitions).pipe(delay(1000))`

Comment: thanks I did want next, complete etc in there though :)

Answer (score 4):

You can set the result of the async operation directly in the *ngIf directive like that:

```
<div class="format-options" *ngIf="definitions | async as defs">
  <div *ngFor="let definition of defs" class="search-result">
    <div>{{definition.name}}</div>
    <div>{{definition.description}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then no need for the second async pipe.

**PS: Never subscribe in your services, pefere using RxJs operators.**

Comment: do you mean the second async

Comment: If I don't use subscribe in a service how can would I implement a timed value? I'm trying to substitute http response because I don't have server setup

Comment: Use rxJs operators, and subscribe only in components. you are trying to delay the response ? so use delay operator